# How can I add html code on WooCommerce after single product summary

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I add HTML code on woocommerce after a single product summary?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Regards
Golam Rabbi

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following for this

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_tabs', 'my_product_after_tabs' );
function my_product_after_tabs() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    
    if ( $product_id == 1 ) {
        echo 'html 1';
    } elseif ( $product_id == 2 ) {
        echo 'html 2';      
    } elseif ( $product_id == 3 ) {
        echo 'html 3';
    } else {
        echo 'product id not found!';       
    }
}
```