# How can I add individual html code on WooCommerce after each single product summary

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How can I add individual HTML code for individual products?

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeGGw.png

Regards 
Golam Rabbi

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday which someone replies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568057/how-can-i-add-html-code-on-woocommerce-after-single-product-summary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add html code on WooCommerce after single product summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568057/how-can-i-add-html-code-on-woocommerce-after-single-product-summary)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function html_below_product_tabs() {
    echo 'Content you want to place';
}   

add_action('woocommerce_product_after_tabs', 'html_below_product_tabs');
```

Comment: I tried this but not working!

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: I put this on function.php file both child and main theme.

Comment: Are you using an opens source theme?

Comment: No, I'm using the "TheGem" theme.

Comment: To bad. I can't view the code then! Can you maybe try this hook? 'woocommerce_after_main_content'

Comment: That should go under all you wc pages, but then you can maybe check for the right page.